# How to print next row of fetched mysql data whenever button is clicked?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Have no idea on how to update or fetch the next row of data when the button is clicked.

I had successfully connected to the database and retrieved the data and tabulated them in the form of a result table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/html.css">
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to my quiz! \(* 3 *)/</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Welcome to my quiz</h1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/background.css">

    <?php


         $conn = new mysqli("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizapp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "myuser", "1234");

         $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD FROM question");

         $count=0;

        if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
            echo $row['id']. ". " . $row['question'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "A. ".$row['optionA'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "B. ".$row['optionB'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "C. ".$row['optionC'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "D. ".$row['optionD'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
          }


    ?>   

 <form> <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="alert('You clicked the button!')"> </form>




  </body>
</html>
```

In what way I can code it so that I can proceed to the next row of data ( next question with option A, B, C, D ) when the button is clicked?

Comment: Tried to add a variable called counter to track the number of clicks, not sure how to implement that.

Comment: use the `limit` clause of sql and pass the current position via the form?